# Scala regex: how to extract year from string?

Tags: regex, scala

Trying to extract years from String, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
val p = "(19|20)\\d\\d".r
val str = "At the time of its release, Twilight Princess was considered the greatest entry in the Zelda series by many critics, including writers for 1UP.com, Computer and Video Games, Electronic Gaming Monthly, Game Informer, GamesRadar, IGN, and The Washington Post. It received several Game of the Year awards, and was the most critically acclaimed game of 2006. In 2011, the Wii version was rereleased under the Nintendo Selects label. A high-definition port for the Wii U, The Legend of Zelda: Twilight Princess HD, will be released in March 2016."
println(p.findAllIn(str).toSeq)
```

it gives me:

```
Seq[String] = Stream(2006, ?)
```

missing a "2016" and "2011" plus an extra "?". Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code works well, the reason why you are not seeing all the matches is becase findAll returns an iterator, if you convert it to a Seq it will pick the Stream collection that is a lazy collection (it will perform the matching as you requests elements)

To see all the results do this

```
println(p.findAllIn(str).toList)
```

This will convert the iterator to a List (this operation will extract all matching years).

The meaning of that ? is that the next element of the stream has not been computed yet